# PHP form will send an email, but no message or other variables

Tags: php, email, forms, message

I'm pretty new to PHP so I am not really sure what i am doing wrong here.  I can get it to send the email, but it comes up as "unknown sender" and there is no message.  What am I doing wrong?  Please help!

```
 <? 

    $userFirstName = $_GET["txtFirstName"];
    $userLastName = $_GET["txtLastName"];
    $userEmail = $_GET["txtEmail"];
    $userPhone = $_GET["txtPhone"];
    $userComment = $_GET["txtComment"];

    $to = "arandomEmail@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "From randomURL.com"; 
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
     $message = $_REQUEST["This message is from " .$userFirstName. " " .$userLastName. ".\n  
                          Their phone number is " .$userPhone. " and has this comment/question: \n" .$userComment. "."] ;
    $headers = "From: $email"; 
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 

    if($sent) {
        print("Your mail was sent successfully"); 
        } 
    else {
        print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; 
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Consider http://swiftmailer.org/ or another lib for production.

Answer (score 1):

The message should not be pulling from $_REQUEST

```
$message = "This message is from " .$userFirstName. " " .$userLastName. ".\n  
   Their phone number is " .$userPhone. " and has this comment/question: \n".$userComment. ".";
```

Also check if you are actually giving the script the from email in $_REQUEST.  The assumption here is that you are bringing it in using either POST or GET.  You can check what is in $_REQUEST using

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```